# Does the .NET Framework need to be reoptimized after upgrading to a new CPU microarchitecture?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, .net-framework

I believe that the .NET Framework will optimize certain binaries targeting features specific to the machine it's installed on.

After changing the CPU from an Intel Nehalem to a Haswell chip, should the optimization be run again manually? If so, what is the process for that?

Between generations here are some notable additions:

- **Westmere**: [AES instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set)
- **Sandy Bridge**: [Advanced Vector Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)
- **Ivy Bridge**: [RdRand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) (hardware random number generator), [F16C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F16C) (16-bit Floating-point conversion instructions)
- **Haswell**: [Haswell New Instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_New_Instructions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions_2) (includes Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX2), gather, BMI1, BMI2, ABM and FMA3 support)

So my, albeit naive, thought process was that the optimizations could take advantage of these in general cases. For example, perhaps calls to the Random library could utilize the hardware-RNG on Ivy Bridge and later models.

Comment: You don't have a different architecture, both CPUs, are x86-64 processors.  Why would you need to regenerated your documentation nothing changed.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I mean micro-architecture.

Comment: Where did you hear about this so called optimization, I want to contact the author of said information, and give him a virtual slap for giving out bad information.

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure, but I think it was one of those C# Step-by-Step books (from Microsoft Press!).

Comment: The image generated wouldn't be any different from what you already generated.  If you really believe it might help just generate the image again, exactly the same way, [you originally did it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The processor specific code isn't going to change, since you were not specific about what exactly change, can't get more specific.

Comment: @Ramhound It runs automatically after installing the framework, but I'm not sure how to use the tool. Using the update flag throws pages of errors. But the idea is that instead of using the JIT, it will precompile certain code to take advantage of CPU features. For example, a binary on a CPU with SSE2 might be different from one with a CPU that supports SSE3. I believe that's the general idea.

Comment: Update your question.  Be specific about what CPU you were using and what CPU you upgraded to.  Additionally, if your getting errors provide them, we need specifics.  **I required facts not guess work in order to formulate an answer**

Comment: @Ramhound Well I'm not asking about my specific computer. I'm just wondering if the assemblies need to be reoptimized in such a situation.

Comment: @Louis and what Ramhound is trying to say is you have not given enough details to give you a yes or no answer yet on if running `ngen` would be necessary or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Okay, I'll add an example, but I though each new microarchitecture always introduced some new extensions.

Comment: @Louis - We still need the error if you want help.  You lose nothing be running the command again, I guarantee you it won't make a difference, all the processors on the market are all nearly identical.  But .NET isn't going to use those Random instructions I guarantee you that.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, no problem. I saved the output from the first run just in case: [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/2cbd249101090835e092/raw/5b78a3c13533a294847619d19270d1f0bf1cc33c/gistfile1.txt). It was able to compile a few assemblies in the middle and at the very end (you can search for `1>` to jump to them). Just did a second run: [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66c25eae41f7a1ffa53c). It's almost identical, but doesn't compile anything and ends with `All compilation targets are up to date.` So maybe it did work? But I was just curious if it the idea was sound.

Comment: @Louis I believe the book you were referring to is [CLR via C#](http://books.google.com/books?id=36tCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&dq=ngen+cpu+type&hl=en) by Jeffrey Richter.

Comment: Possibly, thanks. I haven't read that book, but did glance through some edition of it. I hope Richter can get a restraining order on @Ramhound

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

It doesn't need to, as of now.

## Long answer

Code that targets the .NET Framework [Common Language Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) (CLR) is known as *managed* code, and code that doesn't is known as *unmanaged*.

> When compiling to managed code, the compiler translates your source code into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), which is a CPU-independent set of instructions that can be efficiently converted to native code.
>
> Before you can run Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), it must be compiled against the common language runtime to native code for the target machine architecture. The .NET Framework provides two ways to perform this conversion:
>
> - A .NET Framework just-in-time (JIT) compiler.
> - The .NET Framework [Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator).
>
> <sub>Source: [Managed Execution Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process)</sub>

### JIT compilation

> JIT compilation takes into account the possibility that some code might never be called during execution. Instead of using time and memory to convert all the MSIL in a PE file to native code, it converts the MSIL as needed during execution and stores the resulting native code in memory so that it is accessible for subsequent calls in the context of that process.
>
> <sub>Source: [Managed Execution Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process)</sub>

While in theory the JIT compiler *could* take advantage of CPU-specific instructions like AES or AVX, such optimizations haven't been implemented yet. Full [AVX support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married/) will probably come later with a new release of the .NET runtime that includes [RyuJIT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/30/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler.aspx), the next-gen JIT compiler which is being developed.

### Native images

> [The Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) is a tool that performs an] ahead-of-time compilation [of] MSIL assemblies to native code much like the JIT compiler does. However, the operation of Ngen.exe differs from that of the JIT compiler in three ways:
>
> - It performs the conversion from MSIL to native code before running the application instead of while the application is running.
> - It compiles an entire assembly at a time, instead of one method at a time.
> - It persists the generated code in the Native Image Cache as a file on disk.
>
> <sub>Source: [Managed Execution Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process)</sub>

When you use `ngen.exe` to create native images, the output depends on multiple factors such as the identity of the assemblies, and the framework version. Until version 1.1 of the .NET Framework, the output was also CPU-dependent:

> If you upgrade a computer's processor to a new processor family, all native images stored in the native image cache become invalid.
>
> <sub>Source: [Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) Legacy Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms165073%28v=vs.100%29)</sub>

Starting with version 2.0, some causes of image invalidation (including the CPU type) have been removed. Additionally, a new `/update` switch was added to re-create invalid images. Quoting a blog entry written by David Notario (emphasis mine):

> In previous versions of the CLR (1.0 and 1.1), we treated NGEN compilation the same way as we treated JIT compilation, ie , given that we are compiling in the target machine, we should take advantage of it. However, in Whidbey [Visual Studio 2005], this is not the case. **We assume a PPro instruction set and generate code as if it was targeting a P4.**  Why is this? There was a number of reasons:
>
> - Increase predictability of .NET redist assemblies (makes our support life easier).
> - OEMs and other big customers wanted a single image per platform (for servicing, building and managing reasons).
>
> We could have had a command line option to generate platform specific code in `ngen`, but given that `ngen` is mainly to provide better working set behavior and that this extra option would complicate some other scenarios, we decided not to go for it.
>
> <sub>Source: [Does the JIT take advantage of my CPU?](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011184652/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/08/15/451845.aspx)</sub>

In Windows 8 and later, the .NET Framework is able to automatically generate and maintain native images based on usage. The [Native Image Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/) will do all the work in the background whenever needed, and there's no need for manual intervention.

### Further reading

- [Just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)
- [Does the JIT take advantage of my CPU?](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011184652/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/08/15/451845.aspx)
- [NGEN Primer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150625041754/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/abhinaba/archive/2013/12/10/net-ngen-gac-and-their-interactions.aspx)
- [Native Image Generation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Comment: Wow, you really a fountain of knowledge.